How can I create trigger touch image effect for Anfroid?
How can I create trigger with finger touch image effect for Anfroid like on a GIF?
I intrested only moving effect, without chromatic aberration
Touch image effect
I am a designer, I don't understand code well, I want to ask someone to implement this effect after receiving advice

Welcome to StackOverflow. Reminder that this site works best with specific programming questions. Please read through the tour Don't: Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!) and how to ask. As written your question shows no attempt to solve or research.
